# How to use new variable in Google Chart?

Tags: php, database, laravel

I've made a new variable with this code :

```
$countId2 = Event::selectRaw("category_id,count(id) as count")
                            ->groupBy('category_id')
                            ->orderBy('count','DESC')->skip(1)
                            ->take(1)
                             ->limit('1')
                             ->get();
```

and $countId2 results :

```
{"category_id":"15","count":"4"}
```

It's exactly what I wanted.To count first 3 categories and put it into Google Chart.

**Here is my Google Chart code:**

```
<script>

    var data12 = {{ $countEvents }};
    var data13 = {{ $countNews }}; 
    var data14 = {{ $countOpinion }}; 
 google.charts.load("current", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
          ['Events',    data12],
          ['News',      data13],
          ['Opinions',  data14],

        ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'My Daily Activities',
          pieHole: 0.4,
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('donutchart'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
</script>
```

Previously, I used data 12,data13 and data14 to get an exactly number.Now, I get category ID  with count numbers.How to use this variable instead of data12,data13 and data14? I want to add it to my Goole Chart to be more dinamic.

I want to use category_id instead of Events/News and Opinions, and number of counts instead of data13,data 12 and data14.

Comment: How are you passing data to the view from the controller? Could you paste the code snippet of the same

Comment: I have used $countId2 in the controller and write {{$countId2}} to get the data